# Pivoting a dask dataframe using multiple columns as index

Tags: dask

I have a Dask DataFrame of following format:

```
date       hour device  param     value
20190701    21  dev_01  att_1   0.000000
20190718    22  dev_01  att_2   20.000000
20190718    22  dev_01  att_3   18.611111
20190701    21  dev_01  att_4   18.706083
20190718    22  dev_01  att_5   23.333333
```

I am trying to pivot the dataframe using Dask.DataFrames.pivot_table() API. However, I want to use 'date', 'hour' and 'device' as the index (i.e, in the pivoted table each row would be uniquely identified by the date, hour and device identifier):

```
ddf.pivot_table(index = ['date', 'hour', 'device'], columns='param', values='value')
```

However, it's failing with the following error:

```
'index' must be the name of an existing column
```

As I understand from the API documentation ([here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html)), the parameter 'index' accepts name of a single column (and not a list) and hence this error.

Is there any other alternative of pivoting a dask dataframe using multiple columns as index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the docstring the column on which you pivot must be a single column, and it must be of categorical dtype.  So to accomplish what you want you would have to convert your three columns into a single categorical column.

This is doable using normal Pandas syntax, but will likely require a full pass through the data to get the categories.